# elasticsearch: is it possible to order aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch, faceted-search

Can I add weight to each aggregation to make sure that they return in certain order, for example: `category, manufacturer, color` instead of in the order shown below:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "category": { "terms": { "field": "category" } },
        "manufacturer": { "terms": { "field": "manufacturer" } },
        "color": { "terms": { "field": "color" } }
    }
}

// results

"color": {
    "buckets": [ ... ]
}
"category": {
    "buckets": [ ... ]
}
"manufacturer": {
    "buckets": [ ... ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I add weight to each aggregation to make sure that they return in certain order, for example: category, manufacturer, color instead of in the order shown below

The response is JSON and JSON/JavaScript object keys order is undefined.

Source: http://www.json.org/

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the documentation [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order). , it sheds some insights on how to order your results in terms aggregation.

Comment: I've read the docs, but if I get it right it says about ordering buckets within given aggregation, but I wanted to know if it was possible to order aggregations themselves.